# Understanding linux server process logs

Tags: linux, apache, logging, process, webserver

So I got this little snippet from a server admin saying that my script was responsible for a server overload. I didn't quite understand how this log tells that.

Can some one explain what this output actually means ?

nobody 227949 6.2 45.4 21198032 11187052 ? S 08:40 0:19 _ /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL

user 232019 4.1 0.1 150748 25872 ? S 08:41 0:11 | _ /usr/bin/php /home/user/public_html/results.php

**All I got from this was:**
user processid **__ *_*__** ___ __*_*__ ? S ***_*__** ___   process-location(apache/php) file-in-use

Is that even correct ? Can someone fill in the blanks explaining what's what. And what is S ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is output provided py `ps au` or `ps aux`, the columns are:

`USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND`

https://superuser.com/questions/117913/ps-aux-output-meaning has an explanation, or look at `man ps`.

Status `S` means 'sleeping', which is quite a normal state for a process to be in. This output doesn't really help you that much in tracking down the problem. All you now is that the problem is in `results.php`, so you have to investigate that more closely. I'd hazard a guess and say this script does some data processing which probably takes too long.

Comment: you are right the script is designed to download a large xml file and parse to sql. The two tables involved have ~140 columns and about ~11,000 entries in total between the two tables. 
Also in this case, the apache process being run would be a shared process on the server (user:nobody) or is it mine only ?

Comment: And from the looks of it, the CPU and Mem usage are low for the result.php process
However, virtual memory and resident set (not sure what that is?) are just at 150kb and 25kb. It doesn't seem that bad.

Comment: @xlordvader It's 150MB/25MB respectively. The unit of this output is 1KiB = 1024 Bytes

Comment: Anyway, the breakdown was exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know what was giving this log output. And searching for "linux server process log" didn't get me any possible solutions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What your system administrator is telling you, is that something in results.php was using resources.  He may have been able to surmise this in conjunction with a tool like `top` or `htop` so that he could watch the processes in 'real' time.  Cross referenced the PID (Process ID) and viola he can asses that your file `results.php` was using more resources than 'normal' or 'expected'.  But from the log itself, all that you can see is that a user ran a process numbered `232019` and what that process 'was'.  He needed the log to tell him what PID `232019` was and why said ID was eating resources.  Apache logs are designed for error reporting, not for monitoring kernal processes and their performance.

So in short, I believe the troubleshooting must have go something like:

hmmmmm  Server is slow

Ok I'll look at `HTOP`

`HTOP` says that PID `232019` is pegging the CPU's and eating memory

hmmmmm  Wonder what PID `232019` really is?  -  All I can see is that apache is running it.  Better look in the logs.

Search the log file for `232019`.

Ahh, there it is ...  results.php.  The culprit.

Comment: That was a bit too simple. I wanted to know what specific resources were being used (an explanation of the log itself) that the admin had to block access. Your input is much appreciated - Thanks